# Macro inside Macro

Tags: c, macros

Consider the following code:

```
#define P1(x) x+x
#define P2(x) 2*P1(x)

int main()
{
    int a = P1(1) ? 1 : 0;
    int b = P2(a)&a;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I thought that the compiler first replacing the macros with their values and so `int b = 2*a+a&a;` (and since `a=1` then `b=3`). Why isn't it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `&` has lower [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than that of addition `+` operator. The grouping of operands will take place as

```
int b = ( (2*a + a) & a );
```

Therefore, `(2*a + a) = 3` and `3 & 1 = 1` (`011 & 001 = 001`).

Answer (score 2):

There's no precedence in your operation (it is just a textual substitution) thus, as you've noted,

```
#define P1(x) x+x
#define P2(x) 2*P1(x)

int a = P1(1) ? 1 : 0; // 1
```

and since `&` [has lower precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `+`, it is equivalent to

```
int b = ((2 * a) + a) & a;
```

i.e. only the rightmost bit is set on `b`.

```
((2 * a) + a)  011 &
      a        001 =
--------------------
      b        001
```